# How is 10GBASE-T defined for providing compatibility?

Tags: networking, ethernet, 10gbethernet

Is there a common source for description (like for "data link layer" and might include electrical specification of "physical layer") of 10GBASE-T as standard for technical devices?

Considering multi data rate support (10Gbps, 1Gbps, 100Mbps), modulation type BASE, compatible medium types, coding scheme 4B/5B, 8B/10B or 64B/66B, number of lanes and lane signal rates provided.

(Example, but without description for compatibility definitions for network devices: https://www.synopsys.com/designware-ip/technical-bulletin/ethernet-dwtb-q117.html#Ethernet%20Nomenclature
802.3an is a 2006-06 standard for 10GBase-T, but not publicly available? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

10GBASE-T isn't downward compatible (nor is any other Ethernet physical-layer protocol by itself downward compatible to anything). A *port* labeled "10GBASE-T" may be downward compatible.

Twisted-pair Ethernet uses *Autonegotiation* where each side announces its capabilities (speed, duplex and line code) using Fast Link Pulses (FLP), so the link partners can agree on the best mutually supported protocol before PHY initialization begins.

It's up to a port's capabilities and configuration which protocols it supports and announces. Many 10GBASE-T ports support 1000BASE-T as well, some even 100BASE-TX or 10BASE-T.

The Autonegotiation process is detailed in IEEE 802.3 Clause 28. The protocol priority is selected from the list in Annex 28B, higher is better:

```
a) 40GBASE-T full duplex
b) 25GBASE-T full duplex
c) 10GBASE-T full duplex
d) 5GBASE-T full duplex
e) 2.5GBASE-T full duplex
f) 1000BASE-T full duplex
g) 1000BASE-T (half duplex - obsolete)
h) 100BASE-T2 full duplex (obsolete)
i) 100BASE-TX full duplex
j) 100BASE-T2 (obsolete)
k) 100BASE-T4 (obsolete)
l) 100BASE-TX (half duplex)
m) 10BASE-T full duplex
n) 10BASE-T (half duplex)
```

Comment: Thx Partly different experience, maybe? One device (SPT-PTTG-RS1) known to me (theoretically) seems to provide different functionality, that is not understandable, without "coding translation" between 64b66b and 8b10b and therefore "(auto)negotiation" compatible between 10GBase-T and 1000Base-T http://www.sopto.com.cn/upload/201907/25/201907251646537757.pdf ?

Comment: The PCS coding is different for each speed - there's no translation however, the device uses the right one for each PHY. The transceiver you've linked to does use use trancoding though to convert between 64b66b on the SFP+ slot and 10GBASE-T.